# How to get selected objects from pyautocad

Tags: python

I'm going to use pyautocad, but on pyautocad
Is there a way to send and receive data about selected objects on autocad?

I want anyone to answer because there are not many people using it. Thank you

I've searched a few times, but I can't find it because there are so few data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.